# Unity3d: Object's pass through each other?

Tags: c#, geometry, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Object's(collider) pass through each other? How to fix?

https://youtu.be/gJKCEMNI9ls

[image]
[image]

Comment: When you say collider you are not refering to the overlapping images are you? Because that is just z-fighting due to two objects having the same coordinates

Answer (score 2):

One of your colliders might have the IsTrigger-checkbox ticked, which is causing the ball to jump out. But  I think it's more likely to be that the rigidbody isn't checking for collisions often enough so that when you rotate quickly it clips out.

Change

> Collision Detection: Discrete

to

> Collision Detection: Continous (or Dynamic)

In your Sphere's rigidbody.

Read more about collision detection [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html):

> - **Discrete:**    Use Discreet collision detection against all other colliders in the scene. Other colliders will use Discreet collision detection when testing for collision against it. Used for normal collisions (This is the default value).

- **Continuous:**   Use Discrete collision detection against dynamic colliders (with a rigidbody) and continuous collision detection against static MeshColliders (without a rigidbody). Rigidbodies set to Continuous Dynamic will use continuous collision detection when testing for collision against this rigidbody. Other rigidbodies will use Discreet Collision detection. Used for objects which the Continuous Dynamic detection needs to collide with. (This has a big impact on physics performance, leave it set to Discrete, if you don’t have issues with collisions of fast objects)
- **Continuous Dynamic:**   Use continuous collision detection against objects set to Continuous and Continuous Dynamic Collision. It will also use continuous collision detection against static MeshColliders (without a rigidbody). For all other colliders it uses discreet collision detection. Used for fast moving objects.

Comment: I tried to change the type but there is no result. I checked every object on Trigger-checkbox - everything is false (((

Comment: When does the sphere fall out? Is it always at the same position? Is it when you spin it fast?

Comment: Yes, only with fast rotation. It can drop out anywhere. If there are corners, then most often in them.

Comment: And changing the Collision Detection to Continous didnt work. I suggest you make wider colliders then... Or adjusting your rotating code. How is it rotating? Are you using forces or "teleporting" (setting position) every frame? Because if you move something fast, it means it will travel more pixels every frame. If it moves fast enough it will move (teleport) over the ball and put it outside within a frame. When using physics you should move things with physics. And handle it in FixedUpdate

Comment: I use this code. How right? 
void Update () {
  float h = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
  float v = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
  transform.Rotate(new Vector3(h,0f,v));
 }

Comment: First try putting that code in FixedUpdate() instead of Update()

Comment: If it still doesn't work, try using [rigidbody.MoveRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html).

Comment: Look here please
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B07aYSnGHQe9aGx4d1lkd0FZd0E/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Ok the colliders don't prevent you overlapping gameobjects in the editor. You just need to line up the walls of the maze so they don't cross over (visually) but you can overlap the actual colliders so there are no holes in the maze.

If you really don't want them to overlap then change the position or size of the colliders in the editor.

[image]

You can change the centre and size as shown in the image so they don't overlap.

Comment: I tried to throw balls on the plane (without intersections) in some situations the ball flies through the plane

Comment: Ok quick question. Have you got a mix of planes and boxes to make up the maze? Even if you have planes you should not use a mesh collider, use a box collider and make sure it has some width.

Comment: I tried different options. Sorry, I just delve into this teznologiyu. You can show an example with four walls and an object inside which quickly rotates and with which nothing falls out? ))) Sorry for the arrogance)))

Comment: Not sure what you mean by arrogance there but I just want to eliminate a few things that might fix your problem. I have had problems with objects passing through planes before, I no longer use them. With a combination of @Fredrik suggestions and mine you should get there. 1. Continuous Dynamic 2. No planes 3. Ensure you are using fixed update function 4. Make sure the box colliders are wide enough.

Comment: Look here please
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B07aYSnGHQe9aGx4d1lkd0FZd0E/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Just set the transform's parent of everything that is on the maze to the maze's transform. Simple as that and it solved for me.